# Rails: Return array of all Categories that contain at least one Post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

Given:

```
class Categories < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

and

```
class Posts < ActiveRecord:Base
  attr_accessible :category_id

  belongs_to :category
end
```

How can I get an array of all Categories that have ***at least one*** associated post?

Comment: I haven't implemented it, but I've looked at setting up a counter_cache.  Seems like there must be a simpler way, since my tables are relatively small (fixed at < 2000 rows, actually dealing with municipal data, not posts/categories).

Comment: +1 for counter_cache, no reason to go look it up every time if it's never going to change.  @prasvin's answer looks right.

Comment: It will change slightly over time, but you're right.  By an order of magnitude, this will be retrieving very cacheable counts instead of highly volatile counts.  Was just trying to avoid abstraction—but this seems a reasonable situation for it.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better (in terms of performance) solution is to have a count column in the `categories` table, and `:counter_cache => true` on the belongs_to association declaration (which you have already looked into).

More info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-counter_cache

If your tables are relatively small, you can query : 
`Category.joins(:posts).group(:category_id).having('count(category_id) >= ?', 1)`